# How to write an array of repeated numbers as a single number

Tags: number-representation, digits

Let's say we have a random number consisting of an arbitrary number of digits, such as for example 3097.

This number can be represented as an array of repeated numbers with Mathematica by typing

```
ConstantArray[3097, n]
```

For n = 4 the output is

```
{3097, 3097, 3097, 3097}
```

What is the code to be used to go from the array and write the "continuous" single number 3097309730973097?

What if we want the number to be repeated 3 times (309730973097), or 10 times, etc?

Comment: `{3097, 3097, 3097} // Map[ToString] // Apply[StringJoin] // ToExpression`, for one.

Answer (score 10):

That can easily be done by separating each number into digits and re-assembling them as Number

```
{3097, 3097, 3097, 3097} // IntegerDigits // Flatten // FromDigits
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** A shorter alternative using  `FromDigits` with base `10^commonIntegerLength`:

```
f = FromDigits[#, 10^IntegerLength[#[[1]]]] &;

f @ ConstantArray[3097, 5]
```

> 30973097309730973097

**Timings:** Just in case you need to do this for a large number of long integers, timings for the methods posted so far (`fdfid` below is the function `FromDigits@Flatten@IntegerDigits@#&` from halirutan's answer):

```
SeedRandom[1]
n = RandomInteger[10^16];
m = 100000;
t1 = First[RepeatedTiming[r1 = f@ConstantArray[n, m];]];
t2 = First[RepeatedTiming[r2 = catenateInteger@ConstantArray[n, m];]];
t3 = First[RepeatedTiming[r3 = fdfid @ ConstantArray[n, m];]];
t4 = TimeConstrained[First[RepeatedTiming[r4 = myfun[n, m];]], 5];

Grid[{{"function:", "f", "catenateInteger", "fdfid", "myfun"}, 
 {"timing:", 0.0950, 0.169, 0.637, $Aborted}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

```
r1 == r2 == r3
```

> True

**Original answer:**

```
catenateInteger = Composition[FromDigits, StringJoin, IntegerString]
catenateInteger @ ConstantArray[3097, 5]
```

> 30973097309730973097

Answer (score 1):

```
myfun[mydig_Integer, mynum_Integer] :=  
 Sum[mydig 10^(i Ceiling[Log[10, mydig]] - mynum), {i, mynum}]
```

so

```
myfun[3097, 4]
```

3097309730973097